# Hibernate EntityInterceptor (EmptyInterceptor): Filter out all @Transaction(readOnly=TRUE) Transactions

Tags: spring, hibernate

I defined and successfully plugged in a Hibernate DB Interceptor which catches all Transactions.

```
public class HibernateTransactionInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void afterTransactionBegin(Transaction tx) {

        System.out.println("Intercepted"); 
        // ...
        super.afterTransactionBegin(tx);        
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="transactionInterceptor" class="myapp.interceptor.HibernateTransactionInterceptor" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <!-- Plug into SessionFactory the Interceptor bean define above -->
  <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="transactionInterceptor" />

  ...
</bean>
```

Now, the Interceptor fires on **all** `@Transaction` service methods. But I need to only intercept `@Transaction(readOnly=FALSE)` methods (i.e., filter out all Read-Only methods). Is there a way to configure that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. There's an easy way to check for Read-Only/non-Read-Only Transactions with a **Spring-level** transaction listener. On the Spring level, rather than Hibernate, there's a method called `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly()`. It can be called from the following implementation of `TransactionSynchronization` which uses a pointcut to intercept all `@Before` `@Transactional` Spring processing.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TransactionSynchronizationAspect implements TransactionSynchronization {   
    
    @Before("@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)")
    public void registerTransactionSynchronization() {
        boolean isReadOnly = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly();
        
        if (!isReadOnly) {
            // ... logic goes here...
        }

        // Continue
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(int status) {
        // No custom code here
    }
}
```

As for the original Hibernate Transaction Listener in the Original Post, that strategy can still be used, but requires a `tx:advice` to restrict the Listener to specified (mapped) Service method names, like so:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor id="managerTx" advice-ref="txAdvice"
        pointcut="execution(* com.app.*.*.service.*.*(..))"/>
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="customTransactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
        <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED" isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

This XML file can be imported with `@ImportResource`. With this strategy, all Write operations would be intercepted with the Listener, while Reads would always go through automatically.